# Contributors Page Innacurate After cvs2git import

Tags: gitlab, cvs2git

We used `cvs2git` and everything worked great the history is there for each commit each and it lists each users associated to the commit.

However the contributors page shows only 1 user made all the commits. The user that it lists doing all the commits is the last user that commited via `cvs`.

`git shortlog --no-merges -6000 -nse`
shows each individual commit done by each user

and going to the contributors page and clicking the history button shows each individual users commit.

But the summary page only shows 1 doing all 1600 of the commits on this project.

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Comment: I doubt this is it, but can you do a `git log --pretty=fuller`. That will tell you if both the 'author' and 'committer' are as expected.

Comment: A second idea is that perhaps GitLab has a way to "import existing repo" which is different from "push into an empty repo" and maybe if you did the latter, it takes the pusher as the person who did all the work.

Comment: @turd-furguson did you figure it out?